# Mantener datos en un formulario php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

require_once("../bd/conexion02.php");
?>
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
<input type="text" name="dniusu" placeholder="DNI"><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHideDiv() {
    var Si = document.getElementById("Si");
    var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
    verificar.style.display = Si.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>
<label>¿Usted tiene SIS?</label>
<label for="Si">
<input type="radio" id="Si" name="rpta" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
Si
</label>
<label for="No">
<input type="radio" id="No" name="rpta" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
No<br>
</label>
<div id="verificar" style="display: none">
<input type="text" name="codiSIS" placeholder="Codigo SIS"><br>
</div>

    <input type="submit" name='verificacion' value='verificacion SIS'>
</form>
  <?php  
if (isset($_POST["verificacion"])) {

    $camposis = $_POST["codiSIS"];
    $campodni = $_POST["dniusu"];

    $consulta_usu =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT dniusu, codigosis FROM sis");

    $numeroFilas=mysqli_num_rows($consulta_usu);

if ($numeroFilas!=0) {
    while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_usu)) {
        $bddniusu=$fila['dniusu'];
        $bdcodiSiS=$fila['codigosis'];
    }
}

if($camposis == $bdcodiSiS){
    if($campodni == $bddniusu){
        echo "El usuario cuenta con SIS";
    }else{
        echo "El codigo SIS pertenece a otra persona";
    } 
}else{
    echo "El codigo SIS no existe";
}

}
```

> En ese pequeño fragmento de mi codigo como puedo mantener los datos del campo dniusu al poner en boton submit y buton radio se mantengan y no se eliminen esos campos por que al momento de poner submit todos los campos automaticamente se eliminan

> Y tambien quisiera saber si se puede hacer que al momento de que el codigo sis no se encontrado o no le pertenezca se pongo en boton NO.

Comment: Se me ocurre que, puedes agregarle a tus inputs el value, por ejemplo, para el campo codigo sis `value="<?php echo $camposis['codiSIS'];?>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el valor no se pierda una vez hecho submit en el formulario, debes revisar si existe ese valor dentro de los postvalues, ya que al hacer submit se guarda en $_POST, por tanto, si quieres seguir mostrando el valor de "codiSIS" tendrás que revisar si existe dentro de $_POST y ponerlo como value dentro del input.

Con la función isset() puedes comprobar la existencia de ese valor en $_POST, y a través de un ternario indicar el value correcto en el input del html.

Para que funcione como quieres, el input debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="text" name="codiSIS" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['codiSIS']) ? $_POST['codiSIS'] ; '';?> " placeholder="Codigo SIS">
```

Comment: Intenta explicarte mejor y explica por que lo haces

Answer (score 0):

tengo el mismo inconveniente... solo que en mi caso traigo los datos de la base de datos... por lo que el input value es el asi...
`value="<?php echo isset($reg_actual['Fabricacion']) ? ($reg_actual['Fabricacion']) : '';?>`    
Como puedo hacer que, si el usuario cambia un valor, este cambio no se elimine cundo hace submit?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Eso no es una respuesta, es más bien otra pregunta. Puedes formular la misma, y poner como enlace, si ofrece el contexto adecuado una referencia a esta. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo dilema desde hace tres días

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
                        <select class="form-control" name="curso_enp" id="curso_enp" required>
                        <?php foreach($dato3->carga_cursos as $centros3=>$nombre_area3){?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $nombre_area3['CVE_CURSO']?>">
                        <?php 
                        //if (isset($_SESSION['curso'])){ 
                            //echo $_SESSION['curso'];
                            // }
                            //else {
                                echo $nombre_area3['NOM_CURSO']." | ".$nombre_area3['CVE_CURSO']."-".$nombre_area3['CVE_PROG'];
                        //}?>
                        </option>
                        <?php }?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cve_prog" id="cve_prog" value="<?php echo $nombre_area3['CVE_PROG']?>">
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="charge_cours" value="Carga participantes" onclick="nombre_cursos2()">
                        </form>
```

Tengo 2   que se llenan por BD, el segundo derivado del primero, y un tercero, según su resultado del 2do. Que es el final, ya que llena una tabla. lo trate de hacer con jquery, pero al parecer no se lleva la conexión SQL SVR con jquery, o tal vez por que el sistema usa el método PDO:: para la conexión de PHP con SQLSRV, pero a su paso, por cada POST SELF, deja en blanco los SELECT y no es correcto, alguien tiene alguna idea? o si quieren ver algo del codigo.

tambien trate con un onclick="function()" pero al ejecutarse la función`introducir el código aquí`, deja de funcionar el POST self.

EL isset tampoco jalo, alguien tiene alguna idea de

Answer (score -1):

Esa es UNA de las razones por las cuales a TODOS mis formularios le meto AJAX nativo (NO JQUERY)

Cuando trabajas los formularios con AJAX se mantienen los valores introducidos, aparte de que es más cómodo y rápido para el usuario

```
(function() {
// 
const temp_url_imc = 'https://tudominio.xyz/?page_id=603';
const frm_imc = document.getElementById("form_imc");
//
//Funcion que simula el uso de jQuery library.
function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
// Add EventListener
frm_imc.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // call Ajax XMLHttpRequest
    Xrequest();
});
//
function Xrequest() {
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //  
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let dataText = (this.responseText);
            //let dataJson = JSON.parse((this.responseText));
            _('div_imc').innerHTML = (dataText);
            console.log(dataText);
        }
    };
    //
    ajax.open('POST', temp_url_imc);
    ajax.send(new FormData(frm_imc));
}
```

})();